# How to Complete this part of the code?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

After I wrote all the code that lets you enter names and number of votes, puts it in a table and gives percentage, i want to add a part to this code that gives me the name of the winner and the candidate who got lowest votes.

Whole Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s  = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter The names And votes ");
    int [] Votes = new int[5];
    String [] names = new String[5];
    double [] Perc = new double[5];
    int sum = 0;
    for ( int i = 0,j = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++, j++){
        names[j] = s.next();
        Votes[i] = s.nextInt();
        sum += Votes[i];
    }
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){
        Perc[i] = ((double)(Votes[i]) / sum ) * 100;
    }
    System.out.println("The total information about the candidates are: ");
    System.out.println("Candidate " + '\t' + "Votes received " + '\t' + " Percentage of votes");
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){
        System.out.printf(names[i] +  '\t' + '\t'  + Votes[i] + '\t' + " \t     " + "%.2f" , Perc[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }



    }

 }
```

i Did this to get the Maximum Votes

```
int max = Votes[0];
    for ( int i = 1 ; i < 5 ; i++){
         if ( max < Votes[i] )
             max = Votes[i];
```

How to relate this to the names[i]?

Note : I tried Posting the output here but it's in showing in a proper form.

Here it is :

```
>  Enter The names And votes 
Example1
6000
example2
5000
example3
4000
example4
3000
example5
2000
The total information about the candidates are: 
Candidate   Votes received   Percentage of votes
Example1        6000            30.00
example2        5000            25.00
example3        4000            20.00
example4        3000            15.00
example5        2000            10.00
```

Comment: there is no need to bold every sentence, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try storing the last 'i' where the max number of votes is. After that, just get the name by getting the element at location i in names[] (names[i]) or the variable where you saved it.

```
int name_index = 0;
int max = Votes[0];
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
     if ( max < Votes[i] ){
         max = Votes[i];
         name_index = i;
        }
   }

 String target_name = names[name_index];
```

This is because you are looping both arrays at the same time, votes and names are in the same locations when indexing.

Comment: mustn't it be int i = 1 ? because it already started from Votes[0]

Comment: it wouldn't matter, for a short loop, it should give the same result. If no item was greater than i=0, name_index will remain = 0.

Comment: well, ahlen :) and welcome to StackOverFlow. Please accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try storing it in a variable.

```
int max_i = 0;
int max = Votes[max_i];
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
     if ( max < Votes[i] ) {
         max_i = i;
         max = Votes[max_i];
     }
}
```

Comment: Oh you mean after this , add insert max_i to names[] ?

Comment: When you have `max_i`, you know that `names[max_i]` is the name with maximum votes.